# Route all TCP traffic from port to another host:port

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, routing, iptables

I have a wireguard config, creating a VPN between a remote server (`10.0.1.1`) and my local machine (`10.0.1.2`), so that the server can reach the local machine and vice versa.

I'd like the server to route all incoming TCP connections on port `8000` to my local machine.

What I tried:

[This answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1104023):

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2:8000
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -d 10.0.1.2 -j MASQUERADE
```

[And this answer (quora)](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-route-traffic-on-a-certain-port-to-another-server):

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2:8000
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Also tried this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 10.0.1.2 --dport 8000 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 8000 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.2:8000
```

None of them worked (cannot reach from the internet).

Of course, I can setup an `nginx` server to do just that, however, it wouldn't be as reliable and robust, as I'd like it to be (e.g. websocket connections).

The VPN connection and the firewalls are working fine: I can both `curl` the server on my local machine from remote server's shell, and I can reach an HTTP server started on remote server's `8000` port. Also, `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` is `1`.